# TSQL 2008 Unpivot XML attributes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to unpivot xml node attributes, where the node name/attribute names are unknown, in TSQL

```
DECLARE @Raw XML = '<contact id=1 firstname="liz" lastname="simple" email="liz@sample.com"/>'
```

I need results that look like:

```
id           1
firstname    liz
lastname     simple
email        liz@sample.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

```
DECLARE @Raw XML = '<contact id="1"
                     firstname="liz"
                     lastname="simple"
                     email="liz@sample.com"/>'
select n.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') name,
       n.n.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') value
  from @raw.nodes('/*/@*') n(n)
```

Result

```
name        value
----------- ----------------
id          1
firstname   liz
lastname    simple
email       liz@sample.com
```

Comment: I get an "warning" in SSMS 2012 on the 2nd n in "n.n.value" ""n" is not a valid function, property, or field"  Query runs correctly, and also appears to run correctly using "n.value". Thanks!